# Detect out of focus keystroke, focus an input and fill it in (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a bit of an issue with a piece of functionality.

When no input is in focus, I want to capture user key presses, focus on a particular input and then transfer all the text they've started typing into it and then anything moving forward that they type until they remove focus on that input.

The problem I have seems to be due to lag of Jquery? If you start typing "This is just a test" into the following JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/bjgngayq/1/

```
HTML: <input type="text" id="search" />

JS:
$(function() {
    $(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
        var tag = e.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
        if (e.which === 115 && tag != 'input' && tag != 'textarea' && tag != 'select') {
            $('#search').focus();
            $('#search').val(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
        }
    });
});
```

It seems to skip the first few letters "Thi" and then doubles the last keypress, you end up with "ss is just a test"

Can someone (if known) shed some light on **why** this is happening and where to look. I'm looking more for a reason than a solution - if I understand the problem, I can work out the solution.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason "Thi" get's cut off is because the `input` isn't getting focused until an "s" is typed. This is because of the inclusion of `e.which === 115` in your condition.

The reason you're getting a double "ss" is because you're getting one "s" manually from this line `$('#search').val(String.fromCharCode(e.which))`, but then also another "s" automatically from actually pressing the "s" key.

This should do the trick:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
        var tag = e.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
        if (tag != 'input' && tag != 'textarea' && tag != 'select') {
            $('#search').focus();
        }
    });
});
```

Alternatively, you could change to a `keyup` event, so the automatic "s" doesn't get typed, since the `input` won't gain focus until afterwards.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bjgngayq/3/

Comment: OK, what if that input was hidden and I had to unhide it first? Then, the focus is seemingly ignored as the element is hidden? Is it possible to put some type of timer on, and cache user keystrokes until the element has focus then copy the cache across and allow keystrokes from then on to append?

Comment: @Trent Is there supposed to be any intentional delay between keypress, unhide, and focus? I'm not sure I understand the need for a timer.

Comment: @Trent Why not just use `.show()` on `keypress` before focusing: https://jsfiddle.net/bjgngayq/5/

Comment: your answer will put me on the right path. I tried to abstract the problem, but it looks like the code I'm trying to sort out is using VelocityJS and key press is activating the slide in of a div, and only once that slide in has completed does the input get focus. Hence if you start typing, it keeps activating the "show" and creates some terrible DOM issues :)